# displaying store address in transactional emails with line breaks

Tags: magento-1.9, transactional-mail

I can get the store contact address to display in the transnational emails using `{{config path="general/store_information/address"}}` 
but the address is displaying without any line breaks, I've look everywhere but I can't find how to display the address with the proper line breaks

Comment: Maybe some screen shots would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `<br>` tag at end of line in admin panel refer to attached screen shot. Hope it will help you.

Admin->System->Configuration->General->Store Information

[image]